# C# - How to handle empty user input?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Hello everyone i'm still a beginner in programming in general. So my question is how to handle empty user input in my simple code?, it give's me error every time i press enter with out a value.
My code:

```
    //Program to find the number is even or odd.
using System;
using System.Collection.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace practice
   {
     class test
     {
       static void Main (String[] args)
        {
          int i;
            Console.Write (" Enter a number: ");
            i = int.parse (Console.ReadLine()); // Where the error occurs when there is no user input.
             if(i % 2 ==0)
              {
                Console.Write (" The number is even");
                Console.Read();
              }
               else
                {
                 Console.Write (" The number is odd");
                 Console.Read();
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Try using int.TryParse() instead-- if the parse fails, you can loop to demand the user re-enters the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`. That way an exception isn't thrown and you can test if the value is valid and ask again if not.
2. Wrap the code in a `try` `catch` block to handle the exception gracefully and ask the user to try again.

In the first case, you'd end up with something like:

```
static void Main (String[] args)
{
    int i;
    Console.Write (" Enter a number: ");
    bool result = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i);
    if (result)
    {
        // your normal code
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That wasn't a number.");
    }
}
```

In the second case, it would be something like:

```
static void Main (String[] args)
{
    int i;
    try
    {
        Console.Write (" Enter a number: ");
        i = int.parse (Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That wasn't a number.");
        return;
    }

    // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)){
 //Non empty input
}else{
 //Handle here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for empty user input by using the [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. This method checks for empty spaces or null input on any input.

You can check your input like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
{
   ...//parse
}
```

Since you are parsing an integer however, you may want to use the [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function to parse the data.  It will return a boolean indicating whether or not the input was parsed successfully.

```
int i =0;
if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i))
{
  ...//continue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i;
        Console.Write(" Enter a number: ");

        if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i))
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.Write(" The number is even");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(" The number is odd");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(" You have to enter a number I can parse into an integer, dummy!");
        }
    }
```